# Unit test TypeError: _reactRouterDom.useHistory.mockReturnValue is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-router, react-router-dom

I try to write unit test with react component implement by typescript, but I got an error when mock some hook function.

My unit test implement:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyComponent } from './index';
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
useHistory: () => ({ replace: jest.fn() ]),
}));

describe('MyComponent', () => {
it('Should pass', () => {
  // My render implementation
  (useHistory as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({ pathname: '/test' });
});
});
```

When I run test case it throw an error:

> TypeError: _reactRouterDom.useHistory.mockReturnValue is not a
> function

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've assigned an anonymous function to `useHistory` instead of the mock function created by `jest.fn()`. `.mockReturnValue()` method exists on `jest.fn()`. Try:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as object),
  useHistory: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    (useHistory as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({ location: { pathname: '/test' } });
    const history = useHistory();
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/test');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have adjusted my implementaion according to your suggestion, and It worked

Comment: After hours of googling, finally found your answer which solved the problem! thanks

Comment: @Yingchen Well, it's **not** a recommended way anymore. Because it tests the implementation details. Instead we should use `MemoryRouter` or `createMemoryHistory` to test it, see https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing